# hex в запросе mysql

Tags: mysql

Объясните, почему этот запрос выдает результат

```
select * from tables where id_banner = 1 or num_blok = 21
```

а этот запрос (аналогичный в hex) выводит пустоту

```
select * from tables where id_banner = 0x31206f72206e756d5f626c6f6b203d203231
```

Comment: А в чем подобность запросов? В первом у вас два условия, во втором - одно.

Comment: а разве hex не  расшифровуется аналогично первому запросу ?

Comment: Очевидно нет, если оно не работает.

Comment: вы можете объяснить почему (то что он не работает я тоже вижу)?

Comment: MySQL запрос - это строка, с ней не делается никаких преобразований программой и её лексическим анализатором. Вы можете использовать встроенные функции HEX и UNHEX, но это обычные операторы и не будут изменять СТРОКУ запроса, а только передаваемое им значение.

Comment: так 0x... для MySQL это одно значение, абсолютно такое же как обычное число (правда он его как blob разворачивает, но это уже детали). Причем именно число (4.2795391832849E+42), а не строка. В символы, составляющие текст запроса, MySQL ничего не разворачивает.